# SSL Network Extender on Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, vpn, checkpoint

I have some troubles with SNX on Fedora 35. I've installed libX11, libstdc++ and pam, but I get ./snx_install.sh: line 71: /usr/bin/snx: No such file or directory. How to setup SNX properly?

Or maybe there is another way to connect with Checkpoint VPN?

Comment: This is the list of packages you must install: `libx11-6:i386 libpam0g:i386 libstdc++5:i386 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`

Comment: Now I get conflict between pam-1.5.2-7.fc35.i686 and pam-1.5.2-5.fc35.x86_64

Comment: Honza, install both 32 and 64 bit versions (but the same release, for example 1.5.2-7)

Comment: use this script https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn